# Como obtengo todo los elementos hijos de una clase para ejecutar un evento

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Quiero que al pasar el cursar en una imagen se genere un evento click pero no me reconoce todos los elemento hijos con children. No me aparece nada en la consola para testear el evento click. Solo quiero que al seleccionar la imagen genere un evento click para ampliar la imagen como en una galería. Espero su respuesta saludos

```js
var lupa = document.getElementById('lupa');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  var x = e.pageX - 10;
  var y = e.pageY - 10;
  lupa.style = 'left:' + x + 'px; top:' + y + 'px;';
});

const grid = document.querySelector('.card-content');
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  grid.innerHTML += `<div class='box-${i}'></div>`;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  let random = Math.trunc(Math.random()*100);
  let div = document.querySelectorAll('.card-content > div')[random];
  div.innerHTML = `<img src='img/card/${i}.jpg'>`;
}

//Error aqui no me reconoce los elementos hijos
const content = document.querySelector('.card-content');
for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
  content[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(content[i])
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="lupa">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="fas fa-search"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-container">
    <h1>
      < 18/100>
    </h1>
    <div class="card-content"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar tu código aquí mismo, si es muy extenso, solo coloca lo necesario para crear un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

Tienes dos problemas con ese código:

1. En esta línea `const content = document.querySelector('.card-content');` estás obteniendo solo el contenedor y no los hijos, sin embargo, intentas usar la variable como si fuera un arreglo para asignar los eventos. Lo adecuado es definirla y obtener los hijos para agregar las imágenes.
2. Ya tienes la variable `grid`, que corresponded a `.card-content`, usa esa misma para obtener los hijos y definir `content`.

```js
var lupa = document.getElementById('lupa');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  var x = e.pageX - 10;
  var y = e.pageY - 10;
  lupa.style = 'left:' + x + 'px; top:' + y + 'px;';
});

const grid = document.querySelector('.card-content');
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  grid.innerHTML += `<div class='box-${i}'></div>`;
}
// Arriba generaste los div, ya puedes obtenerlos en una sola variable
const content = grid.querySelectorAll('div');
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  let random = Math.trunc(Math.random()*100);
  // Usas la variable creada antes del ciclo para asignar la imagen
  let div = content[random];
  div.innerHTML = `<img src='img/card/${i}.jpg'>`;
}

// Recorres todos los divs para asignar evento
content.forEach((div, i) => {
  div.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(i);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="lupa">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="fas fa-search"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-container">
    <h1>
      &lt;18/100&gt;
    </h1>
    <div class="card-content"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias en realidad era const content = document.querySelector('.card-content').children; pero lo borre sin querer al subirlo a stack pero aun así no reconoce a los hijos. Pero ahora ya me resolviste el problema mil gracias T.T

Comment: @MatiasJavier, si te sirvió, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que otros usuarios con problemas similares sepan que pueden aquí está la solución.